# How to replace table name with parameter value while using Spring Data JPA nativeQuery

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

like this:

```
public interface XXXRepository extends CrudRepository<XXX, Integer> {
@Query(value = "select * from ?1 where ...", nativeQuery = true)
List<XXX> findByXXX(String tableName, ...);}
```

It gives MYSQL syntax error with upon codes.
The syntax error shows that the table name in the SQL is surrounded with "'".

Comment: Please post your exception stack.

Answer (score 18):

This is not possible. Parameters are only allowed in the where clause.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a Spring Data repository, you can use `#{#entityName}` SpEL expression as a placeholder for the entity name. Depending on your use case, it is not necessary to use the entity name as method parameter anymore.

I am not sure if this feature works when you use `nativeQuery = true`

See the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions

Comment: It does not work in native query only work with HQL.

Comment: SpEl expressions works for me in native query:
@Query(value = "select '#{#tableName}'", nativeQuery = true)
String selectEntityName();

But I didn't find way to insert real table name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EntityManager` in JPA project.

```java
   @Autowired
   EntityManager entityManager;

   Query createQuery(String tableName) {
       return entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from " + tableName);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround.

It uses javax.persistence.EntityManager and String.format to do that.

```
package com.example.test.dao;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

@Component
public class SomeDao {
    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;

    public List<?> listFoodMoneyDateOfPayment(int departmentId, String sumKey, String tableName) {
        String s = "SELECT SUM(%s) AS money, CONCAT(YEAR(apply_time), '-', MONTH(apply_time)) AS yearmonth " +
                "FROM (%s) WHERE department_id = %d GROUP BY yearmonth";
        String sql = String.format(s, sumKey, tableName, departmentId);
        System.out.println(sql);

        List<?> test = em.createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList();

        return test;
    }
}
```

The invoke code is that:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeDao dao;

    @RequestMapping("/test2")
    public HttpEntity test2() {
        var l = dao.listFoodMoneyDateOfPayment(12, "food_payment", "payment_application");
        System.out.println(l.getClass());
        System.out.println(JSON.toJSONString(l));
        return ResultBean.success();
    }
}
```

And it works well. 
But you should check the arguments passed in.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible with jdbc:

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public String nativeQueryToString(String query) {

    try {

        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, String.class);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```