# Dyamic table name for JPQL / Hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've a database with many thousands of tables that have been (and continue to be) created with a naming strategy - one table per calendar day:

- data_2010_01_01
- data_2010_01_02
- ...
- data_2020_01_01

All tables contain sensor data from the same system in the same shape. So a single entity (lets call it SensorRecord) will absolutely map to all tables.

I'd imagined something like this would work:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM \"?1\"")
Collection<SensorRecord> findSensorDataForDate(String tableName);
```

But it does not, and reading around the topic seems to suggest I am on the wrong path. Most posts on dynamic naming seem to state explicitly that you need one entity per table, but generating thousands of duplicate entities also seems wrong.

How can I use JPA (JPQL?) to work with this data where the table name follows a naming convention and can be changed as part of the query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace table name with value from parameter while using Spring Data JPA nativeQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956013/how-to-replace-table-name-with-value-from-parameter-while-using-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: Partially. One answer says "you can't" and another shows an entity manager code snip without context of why that is the preferred solution. Alex's answer below is a considerably more complete and useful response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are only allowed in the where clause. 
You can create custom repository method returns collection of `SensorRecord` dto. No need to map so many entities. You should get `List<Object []>` as query result and manually create dto objects.

```
    @Autowired 
    EntityManager entityManager;    

    public List<SensorRecord> findSensorDataForDate(LocalDate date) {
           DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy_MM_dd");
           String tableName = "data_" + date.format(formatter);

           Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                             "select t.first_column, t.second_column from " + tableName + " t");

           List<Object[]> queryResults = query.getResultList();

           List<SensorRecord> sensorRecords = new ArrayList<>();
           for (Object[] row : queryResults) {
               SensorRecord record = new SensorRecord();
               record.setFirstParameter((Integer) row[0]);
               record.setSecondParameter((String) row[1]);

               sensorRecords.add(record);
           }

           return sensorRecords;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the worked example. This is very helpful. Seems there is no way to have the table name as a JPQL parameter so this is what I need.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be just syntax error?

This has worked for me:

```
    @Query(value = "select * from job where job.locked = 1 and job.user = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<JobDAO> getJobsForUser(@Param("user") String user);
```

Comment: This example has a fixed table name "job". I need to be able to change the table name. So in your example: select * from job_123 or select * from job_456 ...