# Automatically create db entities based on external list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

Relatively new to Spring Data JPA. I have a use case of a Spring app which, upon startup, reads CSVs from a directory:

```
File1.csv, File2.csv, ..., FileN.csv
```

All the CSVs are guaranteed to have the same 3-column format consisting of a UNIX timestamp, a string and an integer.

For every one of those CSVs, the app needs to create a new table in a MySQL database and insert all the data that is in the CSV in the table. Since I do not know ahead of time how big `N` is, I can't go into my code and create `N` `@Entity` classes and map every CSV row into an instance of such a class.

Additionally, based on the top voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956013/how-to-replace-table-name-with-parameter-value-while-using-spring-data-jpa-nativ), it is NOT possible to have a `@Query` - annotated insertion method where I pass the table name as a parameter, so it doesn't *look* like I can use the traditional pattern of a `JpaRepository` - implementing interface with a `@Query` annotated method like so:

```java
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>{

     @Modifying
     @Query(value = 
           "insert into SOME_TABLE (name, age, email, status) VALUES (:col1, :col2, 
                  :col3)", nativeQuery = true)
      void insertRow(@Param("col1") Timestamp tstamp, @Param("col2") String name, @Param("col3") Integer status)
```

In the example code above, and based on the linked answer, it doesn't look like I can pass `SOME_TABLE` as a parameter to my query.

What other pattern can I use in this situation? Should I perhaps directly use an `EntityManager` field? I have only used JPARepositories so far in my Spring apps, and find myself stuck here.

Comment: I wouldn't involve JPA at all if I were reading CSV data into a database.

Comment: @Kayaman what would be your preferred way to go in this case?

Comment: I would use jdbcTemplate for this use case

Comment: Exactly, there's no point in using an ORM framework since you won't have any classes to map to as the whole thing is dynamic.

Comment: "Exactly, there's no point in using an ORM framework" would have been enough.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to address this by using an appropriately configured `JdbcTemplate` instance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is best addressed without an ORM framework, since I don't a-priori know which class is mapped to which table. I was able to address this by using an appropriately configured `JdbcTemplate` instance.